# How can I translate these sentences into English?

Tags: translation, korean-to-english

I need English translation for those lines please

`제니가 그닥이라고?ㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋ존나 띄워주는 손나은같은애들보다 독보적으로 매력있는데ㅋㄱㅋ막눈인가`
and this

```
연예인 빨아주는 빠들이 존재하니 이런 애들도 저렇게 살수있는거지."
```

Answer (score 3):

I won't breakdown those sentences nor correct their grammar, since they have quite a lot to explain. Let me just give you the basic translations.

> 제니가 그닥이라고?ㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋ존나 띄워주는 손나은같은애들보다 독보적으로 매력있는데ㅋㄱㅋ막눈인가
>
> How come you say Jenny's not good? She's definitely much better than Son Naeun. Are you ****ing ******ed?
>
> 연예인 빨아주는 빠들이 존재하니 이런 애들도 저렇게 살수있는거지.
>
> They cannot be like this without their ****** *BIG* FANS.

Sorry for using vulgar words but that's the way they said. And for my poor English, too. My vocabulary lacks a lot to handle their nuances.